# Save identifiers of pthreads in array

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix, posix

I have this C program that creates a thread tree using pthreads. Every thread has 2 children. If you run the program with the command line argument "3" the recursion stops when the number of leaves are 8 `(2^3)`. So the recursion stops at `2^n`.

Right now when the recursion is finished the leaves of the tree outputs their thread id. However, I want to be able to output the thread id of the leaf's ancestors and itself in order. As an example, if running with the argument `n = 3` the output would be

```
T1.1 T2.1 T3.1 T4.1
T1.1 T2.1 T3.1 T4.2
T1.1 T2.1 T3.2 T4.3
T1.1 T2.1 T3.2 T4.4
T1.1 T2.2 T3.3 T4.5
T1.1 T2.2 T3.3 T4.6
T1.1 T2.2 T3.4 T4.7
T1.1 T2.2 T3.4 T4.8
```

Where `Tx.x` is the different thread-ids.

I tried implementing this using a global array but the problem is that this one gets shared between all the threads and not just the parent thread and its children.

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <time.h>

    void checkArguments(int nbrOfArg);
    void* thread_generation(void* arg_param);
    int calculateStop(int n);

    struct arg_t {
        int arg1; // number of threads created
        int arg2; // when to stop creating new children
    };

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        int n;
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
        checkArguments(2);
        struct arg_t args;

        args.arg1 = -1;
        args.arg2 = calculateStop(n);

        thread_generation(&args);
    }

    void* thread_generation(void* arg_param){
        int i;
        pthread_t childrenID[2];
        struct arg_t *args;

        args = (struct args_t*) arg_param;
        args->arg1 = args->arg1 + 1; // 1 more thread created

        if(args->argv1 > args->arg2){ // if true end recursion
            printf("Thread %ld \n", pthread_self());
            pthread_exit(NULL); 
        } else {
            for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                pthread_create(&childrenID[i], NULL, thread_generation, (void *) args); // create new thread 
            }
            for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                pthread_join(childrenID[i], NULL); // make parent wait for children
            }
        }
    }

    /** Checks so command line argument is valid **/
    void checkArguments(int nbrOfArg){
        if(nbrOfArg != 2){
            fprintf(stderr, "Wrong number of arguments");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

/** Calculates when the last level of tree is reached and no new children should be created **/   
    int calculateStop(int n){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            sum += pow(2, i);
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Don't implement it with a global array then. What prevents you from using normal argument passing?

Comment: There is one misconception in your description that I'd like to point out: While threads have a parent-child relationship, that relationship is hard to notice in any way. Therefore, thinking about parent threads and child threads is probably not helpful and only confuses what you actually mean!

Comment: @n.m. If I use a pointer to an array in the struct isn't it still shared with all the threads?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I understand what you mean. With children I mean the threads that this thread has created

Comment: Don't share the array. It would be the same as using a global indeed. Use a local variable in each thread function, and copy data between child and parent. By the way your use of `args` is wrong too because you are modifying shared data without synchronisation. It"s the same thing as using a global array really.

Comment: @n.m. could you show with an example?

Comment: Something like `pthread_create(&child, NULL, thread_function, (void *) &argument);` where `argument` is an automatic variable. Or, if you don't join the threads in the same function you create them, `arg_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Argument)); init_argument(arg_ptr); `pthread_create(&child, NULL, thread_function, (void *) arg_ptr);` and don't forget to `free` it when you are done. Your thread_function can write to the argument and it will not interfere with other threads.

Comment: @n.m. Okay thanks I'll look into this. Also, what do you mean with my way of using args is wrong? How should I use it instead?

Comment: You are updating your counter `args->arg1 = args->arg1 + 1` from many threads simultaneously without any synchronisation. This is wrong.